# Building an executable using pyinstaller, with windows default executable icon

Tags: python, icons, pyinstaller

I just need to build an executable using pyinstaller, with the default windows .exe icon.
Or a way to remove/set default windows icon after compiling.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just set the icon yourself after compiling with pyinstaller? But, if you specifically want to set the icon via pyinstaller, have a look at the `--icon` option for the command.

Comment: How can i set default windows icon after compiling?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just use windows default .exe icon, but you can set your own.
Use `pyinstaller --onefile --icon=myicon.ico yourapp.py` for the command, and have `myicon.ico` in that directory or specify which directory.

Comment: Is there a way to set default windows icon after compiling?